# Need to make piechart visible on condition in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

iam building a PIE CHART  in report builder , need to make one pie chart visible on  some condition &click
[image]

by clicking on categories piechart latitude model pie chart should appear but on condition if in categories virtualcount>0.
so following expression iam entering in vsibility expression

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!virtualcount.Value, "DataSet1")>0,1,0)
```

When I run report, it gives me following error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `True` and `False` instead of 1 and 0.

Also keep in mind that the property you are setting is called `Hidden`, meaning a value of `True` will hide the chart, and a value of `False` will not hide the chart. From your question, it is unclear to me if you want the chart displayed or hidden when that condition is met. I *think* you want the 0 and 1 from your expression flipped the other way around, but like I said, it is unclear to me. If this expression does not give you the desired output, try reversing the `True` and `False`:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!virtualcount.Value, "DataSet1") > 0, False, True)
```

Comment: at start i need to hide, once report load if virtualcount>0 it should show else dont show